# Desempenho na hora da consulta ao banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho

Suponhamos que eu tenha um tabela com 100 mil registros, que nesse exemplo irei chamar de dicionario, e terá um `LIMIT` de 1000 resultados.

```
SELECT FROM * dicionario
```

Digamos que hipoteticamente eu já tenha feito uma consulta e nessa consulta eu peguei o ID dos 1000 resultados e transformei em um array.

Levando em conta o desempenho na hora da consulta, valeria mais a pena refazer o `SELECT` utilizando a mesma condição no `WHERE`, ou valeria mais a pena fazer o `SELECT` utilizando no `WHERE` os id que compõe o array, algo como:

```
$arrayId = 1, 20, 101, 345, 800, .... 7001.
SELECT FROM * dicionario WHERE id IN (". $arrayId .")
```

> Minha dúvida surgiu com base na minha situação atual, onde de fato eu já possuo um array com os ID, pois dessa forma acredito que me pouparia alguns SELECT, porém fiquei preocupado com o desempenho e utilização de recursos, como a memória.

Comment: Concordo com a resposta do @msb mas aí eu te pergunto: Será que realmente existe a necessidade de refazer a query? Derrepente a solução é mudar a query um pouco e faze-la apenas uma vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende de muitos fatores, um deles sendo a memória, mas para apenas 1000 registros, se tu não tiver muitas colunas, o ideal na verdade é tu fazer apenas a consulta original já buscando os outros campos que tu quer. 1000 registros de poucas colunas dificilmente vai utilizar um absurdo de memória.

Se tu realmente precisa refazer a consulta, o fator principal sobre qual é mais eficiente é saber quais são os teus índices. Uma consulta para 1000 valores em uma coluna indexada (como geralmente é o caso do ID) provavelmente é mais rápido do que qualquer outra alternativa, mas caso os outros campos usados no teu `WHERE` também sejam indexados, existe uma pequena chance de ser mais rápido.

Mas fundamentalmente, a menos que esta consulta esteja em um loop de muitas iterações, ou este código e servidor estejam rodando numa máquina lenta/velha/limitada, a chance maior é que o teu ganho de performance com uma solução ou outra seja desprezível. ;-)